# How do you call error in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on Bjarne Stroustrup's Chapter 3 in Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++

> Prompt the user to enter the age or the recipient and assign it to an int
>   variable age. Have your program write "I hear you just had a birthday
>   and You are age years old." If age is 0 or less or 110 or more, call
>   error("you're kidding!").

```
cout<<"Enter the age of "<<friend_name<< ".\n";
int age=0;
cin>>age;
if (age==0)
    cout<<"you're kidding!";

if (age>=110)
    cout<<"you're kidding!";

if (age!=0, 110)
    cout<<"I hear you just had a birthday and you are " <<age<< " years old.\n";
```

I tried to do the code above but It kept giving me

> "you're kidding! I hear you you just had a birthday and you are 0 years old"

but I don't think that is right. I think it's supposed to do one or the other and not both but I don't know how to make it do that.

Comment: Read about `else if` in the same book.

Answer (score 7):

`if (age!=0, 110)` is your problem.  The comma operator returns the right-most expression, so that code is equivalent to `if(110)`.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (age!=0, 110)
```

Thats not proper syntax for a conditional.  You need to do:

```
if ( age != 0 && age < 110 )
```

Answer (score 4):

One problem is this: `if (age!=0, 110)`.  That's not doing what you think it is.  If you want to test of the age is greater than zero and less than 110 the test would be:

```
if ((age > 0) && (age < 110))
```

Also, the problem specification says you are to output "you're kidding" for negative ages, too.  You're not handling that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int age;
    cout <<"Enter age of the recipient:\n";
    cin >> age;
    if (age != 0  && age < 110)
    {
        cout <<"I hear you just had a birthday and you are "<<age<<" years old.\n";
    }
   else
    {
        cout <<"Youre kidding.\n";
    }

}
```

Does this code help?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
cout<< "Write the age of the recipient\n";
int age;
cin>>age;
if(age<=0 || age>=110){
    cout<<"you're kidding!"<<endl;}
else{
cout<< " I hear you just had a birthday and you are "<<age<< " years old.";
}
```

return 0;
}